# SourceKitService のCPU使用率が200%越える(Xcode8.0(8A218a), macOS Sierra)

Tags: xcode, swift3

Xcode8 にしてから、SourceKitServiceのCPU使用率が異常に上がります。
対策をご存じでしたら教えてください。

## 概要

コーディング中、SourceKitServiceのCPU使用率が異常に高くなる。
CPU使用率が高い状態の時のアクティビティモニターのScreenShot

[image: Activity Monitor]

## 現象

1. ObjCのプロジェクトに、 `application-Bridging-Header.h` を利用してSwiftのコードを混ぜているプロジェクト
2. Targetの数は100以上ある。（複数のアプリをリリースするためのプロジェクト）
3. Xcode7.xの時はSwift2.2を利用していた
4. Xcode8.0を利用するにあたり、Swift3.0へのconvert済み
5. Convertで、エラーが出る箇所に関して手作業で修正(Swift3.0へ書き換え）をしている。
6. 修正中にBuildエラーが発生すると、CPU使用率が異常なほどに上昇する。
7. Buildエラーが無い場合は、CPU使用率は100%未満
8. DrivedData削除済み([参考1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151954/sourcekitservice-consumes-cpu-and-grinds-xcode-to-a-halt/28183589#28183589)、[参考2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder)）
9. DrivedData削除→Mac再起動→Xcode8起動でも変わらない。

## この現象による不都合

- 補完が遅い
- Buildが遅い
- 不愉快（PCが熱い、ファンがうるさい、若干PC全体の動作が遅い）

## 環境

- macOS Sierra(10.12)
- Xcode8.0 8A218a
- MacBookPro, 13inch, メモリ16G, SSD空き容量20G以上あり

Comment: ソースに型指定なしで割と長い配列の宣言があったりしますか？

Comment: @packet0 無いですね・・・。

Comment: targetが複数あるのですが、それが原因でSourceKitServiceが重くなったりするのでしょうか

Comment: AppleのForumでも同じ件があるようです。 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50593
（解決策は無いようですが）